# flash send request to another server

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2

hi i am sending a flash reqesut to a url when i make request from local computer its working but when i upload on my server its not working i think flash is not sending request from my server to another server

```
//it working 
myvars.sendAndLoad("http://mywebsite.com",myvars,"GET");
gotoAndPlay("thankYou");

//its not working 
myvars.sendAndLoad("http://anotherwebsite.com",myvars,"GET");
gotoAndPlay("thankYou");
```

any ideas thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a crossdomain file on your server
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14213.html